# E-mail sending form php/html

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I,m trying to make a form send an e-mail but im getting page not found error.

This is the form itself

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
<div>
<div class="row half">
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
</div>
<div class="6u">
<input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
<div class="12u">
<input type="text" class="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row half">
<div class="12u">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="12u">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Send Message" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is the PHP file named sendmail.php

```
<?php
  $to = "info@aroundgalaxy.pt";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  //$site = $_REQUEST['site'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  $headers = "noreply@aroundgalaxy.pt";
  $body = "From: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Message: $message";
  $sent = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers) ;
  if($sent)
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'LINK BACK TO CONTACT PAGE';</script>";}
  else
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'LINK BACK TO CONTACT PAGE';</script>";}
?>
```

Am i missing something?
Thanks

Comment: Are the form file and the sendmail.php are in same directory?

Comment: Well is $sent true or false? You echo the same at both conditions so you can't see if mail() is maybe "send" an error (returns false)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes. index.html and sendmail.php are indeed in the same folder

Comment: Must be sendmail.php file location will be different from the current location

Comment: And the file behind LINK BACK TO CONTACT PAGE exists, too?

Comment: @MarcelBalzer Man you are correct, since i suck at php, can you explain to me how to display a popup window saying "Mail Sent!" or "Mail not Sent" on the else?

Comment: You can just use a javascript alert() window to display messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work. I dont think there is a problem with the code. Just make sure both the form page & sendmail.php are on the same directory